# How do browsers assess the origin domain for XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: cross-domain, jsonp, xmlhttprequest

I thought that the origin domain for XMLHttpRequest was the domain that loaded the javascript that is using it.

For instance, It thought that if on a page http://mydomain1.com/ I have:

```
<script src="http://mydomain2.com/script.js" />
```

script.js can interact with mydomain2.com via XHR. This was, I thought, one of the nice things about jsonp.

I am seeing a bit of evidence in some testing that even though JS loads from mydomain2.com, XHR's origin is still mydomain1.com.  Have I just been way off base all this time?

Comment: The nice thing about JSONP is that it bypasses the Same Origin Policy altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the domain of the page (possibly in a frame) which *executes* the JavaScript.

If it were from the domain with which the JavaScript was loaded, what would happen for all the people using `jQuery.ajax` after loading `jQuery` from a CDN (such as [this](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js))?

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) doesn't allow *acting as* another domain, but rather it allows *injecting from* another domain. The *source* URI of the script element is *not restricted* to the same domain origin restriction as XHR: in this manner JSONP can be used to freely send data (in the URI) and execute the returned JavaScript (not JSON) directly in the context of the current page.

> > **Including script tags from remote sites allows the remote sites to *inject* any content into a website.** If the remote sites have vulnerabilities that allow JavaScript injection, the original site can also be affected.

Happy coding.